# Automatically Create Database in Entity Framework 6 with Automatic Migrations Disabled

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to be able to automatically create a new database, if it does not exist, using code-first EF6 but with automatic migrations disabled.

If i recall correctly, before automatic migrations existed in Entity Framework, this worked just fine.  However, in EF6, I receive the following exception:

> *An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code*
>
> *Additional information: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic
>   migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a
>   code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.*

To verify that this exception was not caused by a external factor in my production project, I created a new test project.  However, I get the same exception.

For my database context, I have:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
    }
}
```

Then I added a database migrations configuration file to disable automatic migrations:

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public DatabaseConfiguration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

I just need to be able to create a new database if one does not exist (so I can quickly delete and recreate a new database for rapid development on my dev machine).  However, I don't want to enable automatic migrations because we do migrations in production with 3rd party tools, and EF6 complains if the schema has changed when automatic migrations is enabled.

Any insight or alternative options that address these needs would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you still using code first migrations to track model changes?

Comment: No, we're using Red Gate SQL Compare to track changes to the database scheme.

Comment: but you still have a migrations folder and a `DbMigrationsConfiguration`?

Comment: No, there is no migrations folder either in visual studio or in the file system.  I created the DbMigrationsConfiguration subclass specifically to disable automatic migrations.  So to the best of my knowledge, code-first migrations has never been enabled or used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could...

1. Set the database initializer to null (to disable the check for model compatibility)

   ```
   public class MyContext : DbContext
   {
       static MyContext()
       {
           Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Explicitly call [`MyContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.database.createifnotexists(v=vs.113).aspx) at an appropriate time of your choosing.

---

#### Edit

If you're not using Code First Migrations, it looks like you need to remove the `DbMigrationsConfiguration`:

> At run time, Code First looks for a DbMigrationsConfiguration class that’s tied to a context when that context goes through its data­base initialization process. If that class is found, any explicit calls or settings to set database initialization to any of the original three initializers—whose job is to create or drop and create the database—will create the database using the migrations.

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818489.aspx*

I'm thinking it must be doing the same thing even if you don't use an initializer.

Comment: I just gave your suggestion a try, but it still throws the same exception.

Comment: @MatthewRenze: prooooobably not what's causing the exception (since I'm sure you would have added it yourself to get it to work) -- but I forgot the type parameter. In any case, not sure why you'd still get that exception. Have you used code first migrations on this project in the past?

Comment: When I tested your code, I copy/pasted it directly into a new test project that has never used code-first migrations.  So, no, the project has not used code-first migrations in the past.  In addition, as you pointed out, I did add the missing type parameter when intellisense prompted me to do so.  Are you able to get your code sample to work in an isolated test project?

Comment: @MatthewRenze: yeah, it looks like it works. New console application, context with that intializer, one DbSet property, one model class with two properties. Called `CreateIfNotExists`, added an entity, saved changes, created a new context, loaded it. Didn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: I tried it a second time from scratch, but it still does not seem to work (i.e. I still get the same exception).  I posted the code I'm using on github using gist at the following URL.  Would you be willing to take a look and see if I'm doing anything different from what you are doing?  Thanks!  https://gist.github.com/matthewrenze/8101479dcc28d343c874

Comment: What you have on the gist looks very similar to mine, except I don't have the `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class. In fact, if the database doesn't exist and I add that class, I get your error. So that must be it. I found an article about this as well -- see the edit.

Comment: Excellent!  That solved the problem!  Thank you so much for spending the time and effort to help me resolve this issue.